# Can we call DataContext.ExecuteCommand(sqlQuery) on SqlCE LinqToSQL for WP8?

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

Currently I see in this post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202872(v=vs.105).aspx that is lack of some essential function for using like as DataContext.ExecuteCommand().
Is there anyway to implement this for my DataContext?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to implement that on Windows Phone